# jQuery executing the else statement if none of the items are found

Tags: javascript, json, html

When the page loads (Feb 6 2017), everything is great. However if the user changes the date to 2/13/2017 using the input (date selector). I get "No Schedule". However I know that there is a valid date because the JSON file has an entry for that date.

I don't understand why I am executing the "else" part. I was trying to show that there was no schedule set IF the JSON file did not have an entry.

```
$.each(sam.smith, function(i, v) {
        console.log("value of i is " + i + " and the value of v is " + v.date);
        if(v.date == theSelectedDate)
        {
            $('.sam.smithName').html(v.name + "<br>");
            $('.sam.smithTitle').html(v.title);
            $('.sam.smithMondaySchedule').html(v.mondayAM + "<br>" + v.mondayPM);
            $('.sam.smithTuesdaySchedule').html(v.tuesdayAM + "<br>" + v.tuesdayPM);
            $('.sam.smithWednesdaySchedule').html(v.wednesdayAM + "<br>" + v.wednesdayPM);
            $('.sam.smithThursdaySchedule').html(v.thursdayAM + "<br>" + v.thursdayPM);
            $('.sam.smithFridaySchedule').html(v.fridayAM + "<br>" + v.fridayPM);
            return false;
        } else {
            v.mondayAM = "No Schedule";
            v.mondayPM = "No Schedule";
            v.tuesdayAM = "No Schedule"
            v.tuesdayPM = "No Schedule";
            v.wednesdayAM = "No Schedule";
            v.wednesdayPM = "No Schedule";
            v.thursdayAM = "No Schedule";
            v.thursdayPM = "No Schedule";
            v.fridayAM = "No Schedule";
            v.fridayPM = "No Schedule";
            $('.sam.smithName').html(v.name + "<br>");
            $('.sam.smithTitle').html(v.title);
            $('.sam.smithMondaySchedule').html(v.mondayAM + "<br>" + v.mondayPM);
            $('.sam.smithTuesdaySchedule').html(v.tuesdayAM + "<br>" + v.tuesdayPM);
            $('.sam.smithWednesdaySchedule').html(v.wednesdayAM + "<br>" + v.wednesdayPM);
            $('.sam.smithThursdaySchedule').html(v.thursdayAM + "<br>" + v.thursdayPM);
            $('.sam.smithFridaySchedule').html(v.fridayAM + "<br>" + v.fridayPM);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

My JS file with a JSON Object in it

```
var sam.smith = [
    {
        "name": "Sam Smith",
        "date": "02/6/2017",
        "title": "Lead Developer",
        "mondayAM": "Ex. Campus AM",
        "mondayPM": "Main Campus PM",
        "tuesdayAM": "Main Campus AM",
        "tuesdayPM": "Main Campus PM",
        "wednesdayAM": "Main Campus AM",
        "wednesdayPM": "Main Campus PM",
        "thursdayAM": "Main Campus AM",
        "thursdayPM": "Main Campus PM",
        "fridayAM": "Main Campus AM",
        "fridayPM": "Main Campus PM",
        "saturdayAM": "Main Campus AM",
        "saturdayPM": "Main Campus PM"
    },
    {
        "name": "Sam Smith",
        "date": "02/13/2017",
        "title": "Lead Developer",
        "mondayAM": "Main Campus AM",
        "mondayPM": "Main Campus PM",
        "tuesdayAM": "Main Campus AM",
        "tuesdayPM": "Main Campus PM",
        "wednesdayAM": "Main Campus AM",
        "wednesdayPM": "Main Campus PM",
        "thursdayAM": "Main Campus AM",
        "thursdayPM": "Main Campus PM",
        "fridayAM": "Main Campus AM",
        "fridayPM": "Main Campus PM",
        "saturdayAM": "Main Campus AM",
        "saturdayPM": "Main Campus PM"
    }
];
```

The HTML file snippet

```
        <input type="date" id="date" step="7" min="2017-02-06" />
```

and the part that affects the table

```
        <tr>
            <td class="lalign"><span class="sam.smithName"></span><span class="sam.smithTitle" style="color: navy;text-align: center;"></span></td>
            <td><span class="sam.smithMondaySchedule"></span></td>
            <td><span class="sam.smithTuesdaySchedule"></span></td>
            <td><span class="sam.smithWednesdaySchedule"></span></td>
            <td><span class="sam.smithThursdaySchedule"></span></td>
            <td><span class="sam.smithFridaySchedule"></span></td>              
        </tr>
```

Comment: First of all: classnames with dots? `:-O` I see you are not using for CSS but it's totally incorrect. I'm very interesting on knowing why this works for you: `$('.sam.smithTuesdaySchedule')` instead of `$('.sam\\.smithTuesdaySchedule')`

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude I wish I could explain it to you. I saw a website that had used it in their example and I used it as a template.

Comment: I see the problem but I dont know how to solve it. It looks like I am not parsing my JSON object.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the format of `selectedDate`. If it is set using the `value` of date input, the condition `v.date == theSelectedDate` will fail.

`v.date` is in the format **mm/dd/yyyy** but `theSelectedDate` will be in the format **yyyy-mm-dd**.

JSFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/zpop5on6/1/

Also don't set properties of `v` as it will result in losing data

```
v.mondayAM = "No Schedule";
v.mondayPM = "No Schedule";
v.tuesdayAM = "No Schedule"
v.tuesdayPM = "No Schedule";
v.wednesdayAM = "No Schedule";
v.wednesdayPM = "No Schedule";
v.thursdayAM = "No Schedule";
v.thursdayPM = "No Schedule";
v.fridayAM = "No Schedule";
v.fridayPM = "No Schedule";
```

Instead you can keep a single variable for this as shown below.

```
var noSchedule = "No Schedule";
$.each(sam.smith, function(i, v) {
  console.log("value of i is " + i + " and the value of v is " + v.date);
  if (v.date == theSelectedDate) {
    $('.sam.smithName').html(v.name + "<br>");
    $('.sam.smithTitle').html(v.title);
    $('.sam.smithMondaySchedule').html(v.mondayAM + "<br>" + v.mondayPM);
    $('.sam.smithTuesdaySchedule').html(v.tuesdayAM + "<br>" + v.tuesdayPM);
    $('.sam.smithWednesdaySchedule').html(v.wednesdayAM + "<br>" + v.wednesdayPM);
    $('.sam.smithThursdaySchedule').html(v.thursdayAM + "<br>" + v.thursdayPM);
    $('.sam.smithFridaySchedule').html(v.fridayAM + "<br>" + v.fridayPM);
  } else {
    $('.sam.smithName').html(v.name + "<br>");
    $('.sam.smithTitle').html(v.title);
    $('.sam.smithMondaySchedule').html(noSchedule + "<br>" + noSchedule);
    $('.sam.smithTuesdaySchedule').html(noSchedule + "<br>" + noSchedule);
    $('.sam.smithWednesdaySchedule').html(noSchedule + "<br>" + noSchedule);
    $('.sam.smithThursdaySchedule').html(noSchedule + "<br>" + noSchedule);
    $('.sam.smithFridaySchedule').html(noSchedule + "<br>" + noSchedule);
  }
});
```

Comment: I fixed the formatting in my function.

        var theSelectedDate = $('#date').val();
 var parts = theSelectedDate.split('-');
 parts[2] = parseInt(parts[2]);
 theSelectedDate = parts[1] + "/" + parts[2] + "/" + parts[0];

Comment: No. I had always had the code in my function to change the format of the date but I think I see the problem. Its not searching in my JSON object (after the 1st entry).

I added console.log("value of i is " + i + " and the value of v.date is " + v.date); and the v.date is always the same no matter what date is selected. v.date is coming from my JSON file (first entry)

Comment: I have updated the answer. Can you check that also ?

Answer (score 1):

Every time user sending you a data your function iterating from first element in your JSON file, that why Feb 6 2017 passes (it is the first date), but when your v.date changing, iterating starting from first element in your JSON file, where date is 02/6/2017. You need to check entirely your JSON file and then go to else block.